# Find a product based on existing/not existing value in the field

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I am trying to find all the products that have a price in the field, but no description.
I have tried that:

```
db.collection.find({ "price": { $ne: null } }, { "description" : null})
```

I get a result, but I actually checked some products by the id and they had a description, so that query is not correct.
I also have a problem with that query (find items with description field not null):

```
db.collection.find({ "description" : {$ne:null}})
```

I am getting results with items that have no description. The thing is, that some items have that field and some doesn't. That query, list items that doesn't have that field, but it shows items with `description:""`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give some example documents please?

Comment: @KevinSmith what do you mean by example documents?

Comment: What your documents look like which you are trying to match and not match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom had kinda the answer but put the filter in the second argument which is projection, try:

```js
db.collection.find( { "price": { $ne: null }, "description" : { $exists: false } } )
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between "exists and is null" to "does not exists".

Change your query to use [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) to detect documents without this field.

```
db.collection.find({ "price": { $ne: null }, { "description" : { $exists: false })
```

Comment: I get an error `"Unsupported projection option: description: { $exists: false }"`

Comment: when I run `db.collection.find( { "description" : { $exists: false }})` it works, so there's a problem with connecting price and description

Comment: I just had a miss-type because i copied it. fixed now.